# does Iranian Filimo website give the foreign films copyright

Tags: copyright

I have bought [Filimo](https://filimo.com) account and think according some Iran relation problem with others world, i want to know does Iranian [Filimo](https://filimo.com) website give the foreign films copyright [like this film](https://www.filimo.com/m/uMV5l/%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C) ?

If not, for me as user of that website, according the Iranian law or international law, is it legal, to see the foreign films in this site even by paying fee.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can tell, because we have no way to know if the site has a license to make that film available. The situation with [Iranian copyright law](https://web.archive.org/web/20110605215535/http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/text.jsp?file_id=197798) is unclear. The law itself makes it a crime to infringe copyright, and the law does not say that it applies only to works created in Iran – basically, the law doesn't saw what works are covered. The Ministry of Culture and Arts (ca. 1970) theoretically had regulations regarding registration of copyright. In theory, legal action could be taken against someone, but again it's impossible to tell what regulations implementing the law are in force. There is no way to know if the movie producers registered copyright in Iran.

The wording of the law is not clear as to whether "secondary infringers", i.e. customers, could be liable under Iranian law, because there was no such thing as "downloading" when the law came into existence. Downloading is not printing, publishing, broadcasting or distributing, which are prohibited without permission. Plus, the English translation has no legal standing in Iran and the Farsi text is not available.

From the perspective of Norwegian law, it would not matter whether you paid for a membership thinking that that gave you the right to watch whatever content they offer. Downloading / streaming the film would be actionable in Norwegian courts. But Iranian courts will not enforce a Norwegian judgment. So it is illegal, but not enforceably illegal.